# Notification is not showing after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications

I did an update on Android Studio recently and after that, I couldn't get my notification showing.

The codes were working fine initially before the update, so I believe the issue is with the software and not the codes. Is there anything I need to change after updating?

My program will actually display a Toast message and also have a notification saying that an account has been registers(after registering an account). However, right after the toast message, another toast message displaying ,"Developer warning for package"com.example.jianminong.aucon" Failed to post notification channel "personal" See log for more details".

```
public void displayNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.aucon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Welcome " + 
editUsername.getText().toString());
    builder.setContentText("You have just created an account with 
the email of " +editEmail.getText().toString());
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = 
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
}


private void createNotificationChannel(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        CharSequence name = "Personal";
        String description = "HAHA";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name,importance);

        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling somewhere in your code `createNotificationChannel()` method that should create the channel for notification? Because if not, the channel is not created, hence the toast message. You can call it before displaying the notification:

```
public void displayNotification(){
    createNotificationChannel()
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the new notification channels if you are running this on the newer android devices:

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel or it will not appear.

You need to follow this:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: May I know which part of my codes need modification?or is it just a setting in the emulator?

Comment: Make sure you are calling `createNotificationChannel` before calling the `displayNotification`

Comment: Thanks.On top of this, is there any changes to the ParentActivity as well?

Comment: For example:
<activity
            android:name=".CustomerSupport"
            android:label="Customer Support"
            android:parentActivityName=".SignIn" />

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I don't think changes in the AndroidManifest is related to the notification problem, I think you are good ;)

Comment: I mean I am having problem with the parent activity issue as well though, hope you could help me out too. As shown above, it does not return to SignIn page, instead it jumps back to the very first page.

Comment: I will be happy to help you with that, post a detailed question and share it with me. I need more context as the manifest entry is not enough :(

Comment: Ahhh,sadly I can only ask one question over a period of time.

Comment: Can I email you instead?

Comment: There is not PM feature on stackoverflow to share private info, just ping me as soon as you can post it :)

Comment: Hi MoGa, I have posted the question already, but I don't know how to ping you there. Do you mind going there and help me out?Its regarding the Parent Activity.